# Nuxt watch does not redirect

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, router

I have a Nuxt application with profile page. This page has a watcher which checks store.state.auth.isAuthenticated value. If it is false watcher should redirect to login page. The weird is that although the condition is evaluated right it does not redirect to login.

```js
watch: {
    '$store.state.auth.isAuthenticated': {
        imediate: true,
        deep: false,
        handler(newVal) {
            if( !newVal ) this.$router.push({'name': 'login'});
        }
    },
},
```

As I wrote above, condition is evaluated right but it does not trigger $router.push(). I dont understand it. What is wrong with that code?

EDIT: It creates the endless loop in auth.js middleware.

```js
import { createNavigationGuard } from "~/plugins/navigation-guard.js";
export default function (context) {

    if (process.client) {
        const watchedStores = [];
        const unwatchStore = (unwatch) => {
            if (typeof unwatch === "function") {
                unwatch();
            }
        };

        // TODO: Find out whether the watchers persist after each route
        // Unwatch previous route - this could be necessary for performance
        console.log('watchedStores');
        console.log(watchedStores);
        unwatchStore(watchedStores.pop());
        const unwatch = context.store.watch(
            (state) => {
                return state.auth.isAuthenticated;
            },
            (isAuthenticated) => {
                createNavigationGuard(context, isAuthenticated);
            },
            {
                immediate: true,
            }
        );
        // it's not necessary to reassign unwatched variable to undefined with array
        watchedStores.push(unwatch);
    }
    if (process.server) {
        createNavigationGuard(
            context,
            context.store.state.auth.isAuthenticated
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to make a method for the redirect and just call that method in your watch handler?

so instead of this.$router.push do this.redirectUser()

and in the method 'redirectUser()' do:

```
this.$router.push({'name': 'login'})
```